# C# Rest Exception Handling

Tags: c#, json, rest

I am using POST to create orders into another system. My goal is to receive a strongly typed exception object, so I can log the exception message.

I just receive a message that a server error 500 has occurred. Is there a way I can get the error details?

It appears I need to receive the JSON as a string, so I can strong type it to a class of exception. When I call GetResponse(), I get an exception that does not contain the error details.

Here is part of my code:

```
public string CreateOrder(Order order, bool deleteExistingOrder) {
  try {
    string postString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order);

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(m_Url + "/Orders/CreateOrder");
    req.Timeout = 90000;
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.Accept = "application/json";
    req.ContentType = "application/json";
    string userP = m_UserName + ":" + m_Password;
    byte[] authBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userP).ToArray();
    req.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(postString);

    using (Stream sw = req.GetRequestStream()) {
      byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postString);
      sw.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    HttpWebResponse resp = null;
    resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    // Verify HTTP for 200 OK status code
    if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8)) {
        string responseData = sr.ReadToEnd().Replace("\r\n", "");
      }
    }
    return "OK"
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    return String.Format("Error inserting order {0}. {1}", order.orderNumber, ex.ToString());
  }
```

Here is the response:

```
{ "Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Invalid storeId","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":"   at
```

Comment: If you don't have access to it, then see what type of exception is being returned and change your catch to that type instead of Exception. Other than that, your only hope is that InnerException is populated.

Comment: "My goal is to receive a strongly typed exception object, so I can log the exception message." Why do you need to receive a strongly-typed exception object? To log the exception message, all you need is the exception message, right?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior No, if the service is throwing WebFaultException (as it should) then OP will want to be looking at Message and Reason.

Comment: @moarboilerplate: Looks like it's currently throwing a `System.ArgumentException`...

Comment: @StriplingWarrior that ArgumentException is going to be wrapped in a different exception.

Comment: Hi, I solved it with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261986/how-to-get-error-information-when-httpwebrequest-getresponse-fails

Comment: which is final solution for `Rest Exception Handling` (***good pattern and practices***)

Comment: `GetRequestStream` and `GetResponse` can throw ***exceptions***

Comment: Maybe using ***HttpClient*** or ***RestClient***