# C#.net winforms HTTP GET returning internal sever error (500)

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

By requesting through Fiddler or Postman both are returning successful results while requesting from debug mode it is always returning internal server error (500).

**What I have done so far:**

Using Fiddler v4.6.20172.34691:
Here is the sample request:
[Fiddler request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7hwB.png)

Here is the sample response:
[Fiddler response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1UoG.png)

Using Postman v6.1.3:
Here is the sample request and response:
[Postman request and reponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeEvP.png)

For the visual studio part:
Form1 code initialization part:

```
urlparameters = @"?account=" + username;
                        url = "https://" + platform + "/Home/CheckRegAccountAvailable" + urlparameters;
                        method = "GET";
```

clsHttp.cs initialization of httpwebrequest:

```
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
    request.Timeout = _timeout;
    request.Method = _method;
    request.ContentType = _responsetype;

    if (_method != "GET")
    {
        if (_contentlength > 0)
        {
            request.ContentLength = _contentlength;
        }

        if (_isrequestbody)
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(_requestbody);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

clsHttp.cs getting the response:

```
string result = "", _msg = "";

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {

                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            _msg = "Received response...";
            Console.WriteLine(_msg);
            if (_isLog)
                doLogToFile(_filename, _fileextension, _path, _msg);

            if (_isUIRTBLog)
                rtb_AppendText(_rtb, _msg + "\r\n");

            Console.WriteLine(_msg);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

**[Update 1]**

Seems setting the user agent works, for some reason is this a server issue?

**[Update 2]**

Here is the sample WebException.Response I get if I didn't included the user agent which returns an internal server error(500):

CharacterSet: "utf-8" ContentEncoding: "" ContentLength: 36213 ContentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8" Cookies: {System.Net.CookieCollection} Headers: {Content-Length: 36213 Cache-Control: private Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=vjxdzvk43vxif4kkviib5vio; path=/; HttpOnly,locale=zh-CN; path=/; HttpOnly,ASP.NET_SessionId=vjxdzvk43vxif4kkviib5vio; path=/; HttpOnly,locale=zh-CN; path=/; HttpOnly,__RequestVerificationToken=MjSUG0cF0M-T2dE9BmthuQq_8vWLgdne0xPuzZggdMst1jUwfuZ30mDzwAdXFSQBMP8ql9VdbXC-d0cLvgpBiCydvrRk8lvZrStzp6e7cyQ1; path=/; HttpOnly,ARRAffinity=e55696f2f9da07a0a50d293b25a04f89be0f0552dbf622b9a924c6d5d272eff4;Path=/;HttpOnly; Domain=www.iwin98.com Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-AspNetMvc-Version:
5.2 X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN,SAMEORIGIN,SAMEORIGIN X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Tue, 29 May 2018 01:19:08 GMT

}

IsFromCache: false IsMutuallyAuthenticated: false LastModified: {5/29/2018 9:19:17 AM} Method: "GET" ProtocolVersion: {1.1} ResponseUri: {https://www.iwin98.com/Home/CheckRegAccountAvailable?account=username} Server: "Microsoft-IIS/10.0" StatusCode: InternalServerError StatusDescription: "Internal Server Error" SupportsHeaders: true

Comment: So what's the response body for the 500? What's the difference between the PostMan request and the request issued through code? You do see that the user agent isn't set?

Comment: I can't get the response body it is already returning an error at this part: using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()).

Comment: By using those 3rd party applications they returned results, so I'm wondering if I missed out something in my code.

Is the user agent a mandatory for HttpWebRequest? I have been doing a lot of HTTP request lately but I don't set the user agent and they are working fine.

Comment: You can get the response body from an error response. Either by [reading the exception's response's stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261986/how-to-get-error-information-when-httpwebrequest-getresponse-fails) or by letting your request flow through Fiddler and inspecting it there. And no, user agents aren't required, but if that's the only difference between a  working and a non-working request, then you could try that. Probably some server-side software who assumes it's set.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I have updated the question and set the user agent seems fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not set User-Agent request header and the requested URL is propably not smart enought to expect requests without User-Agent. It propably throws NullReferenceException internally.

Add this to your code:

```
request.UserAgent="Some value"
```

Or fix the server if you have control over it.

Comment: @Pavlinll, I'll add the user agent part and will do some test, for the server part we don't have control over it.

Comment: Seems that adding user agent fix the problem, is this a server issue, if the user agent is not set?

Comment: Yes, it's problem of poorly written server that expets optional UserAgent header to be filled everytime.

Comment: Alright this is noted, next time I deal with other http request again I will include user-agent in headers, thanks again.