# Write content to a file on azure storage with using PUT request in C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, rest, azure-files

I am trying to make a put request to Azure storage file, where I want to add some simple contents. I change the URL and add `?comp=range` at the end of the url but I get 403 error in response. I have created a basic console application in .net.

**My Header is :**

```
 const string requestMethod = "PUT";
            string urlPath = strShareName + "/" + "rahila.csv?comp=range";//+ "?comp=range  HTTP/1.1";
            String canonicalizedResource = String.Format("/{0}/{1}/{2}", StorageAccountName, strShareName, strFileName);
            try
            {
                //GetWebRequest(requestMethod, urlPath, canonicalizedResource, "CreateFile");
                HttpWebRequest request = null;
                try
                {
                    const string type = "file";
                    string MethodType = "CreateFile";
                    const string msVersion = "2015-04-05";
                    String dateInRfc1123Format = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    String canonicalizedHeaders = "";
                    string data = "rahila sted";
                    canonicalizedHeaders = String.Format("x-ms-date:{0}\nx-ms-version:{1}", dateInRfc1123Format, msVersion);
                    if (MethodType == "CreateFile")
                    {
                        canonicalizedHeaders = String.Format("x-ms-content-length:65536\nx-ms-date:{0}\nx-ms-type:file\nx-ms-version:{1}", dateInRfc1123Format, msVersion);
                    }

                    String stringToSign = "";


                    stringToSign = String.Format("{0}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{1}\n{2}", requestMethod, canonicalizedHeaders, canonicalizedResource);

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToSign))
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentNullException("canonicalizedString");
                    }

                    String signature;

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToSign))
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentNullException("unsignedString");
                    }

                    if (Convert.FromBase64String(StorageKey) == null)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
                    }

                    Byte[] dataToHmac = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);
                    using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(StorageKey)))
                    {
                        signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
                    }


                    String authorizationHeader = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} {1}:{2}",
                                                               StorageScheme,
                                                               StorageAccountName, signature);
Uri uri = new Uri(FileEndPoint + urlPath);
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
if (requestMethod != "Get")
{
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
}
// string data = "Hello testing";
//int a= ((data.Length) + 1);

request.Method = "PUT";//requestMethod;
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-write", "update");
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", dateInRfc1123Format);
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", msVersion);
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-range", "bytes=0-65535"); // + ((data.Length) - 1));
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
```

the line where i get the exception is in the bold format.

```
HttpWebResponse response = null;
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string returnString = response.StatusCode.ToString();
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue or just guide me how to write content to a simple file on azure storage without using the azure client API.

Comment: I'd look at the response, if I were you. There is a `HttpWebResponse` in the exception that's thrown, and you can retrieve the body from that to see what the error response is. Alternatively, use a tool like Telerik's Fiddler to view the request and error response.

Comment: The response i get is :    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at NewFilecreateandupload.Program.UpdateContet(String strFileName, String Content) in C:\Users\abc\source\repos\NewFilecreateandupload\NewFilecreateandupload\Program.cs:line 406                                                                                                     and the error is The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Comment: That's not the response body, that's the exception. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261986/how-to-get-error-information-when-httpwebrequest-getresponse-fails)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:9917d3cd-f01a-006f-03aa-b400f3000000
Time:2019-12-17T07:22:38.8281666Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request '+in5TbFJHfF9BiLeYFFDGvIqPidiq/vrqB+PtDogboY=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign:

Comment: 'PUT











x-ms-date:Tue, 17 Dec 2019 07:22:23 GMT
x-ms-range:bytes=0-65535
x-ms-type:file
x-ms-version:2015-04-05
x-ms-write:update
/bc365storage/lables/rahila.csv
comp:range'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>

Comment: OK So you're possibly not building your authorization header correctly.

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid. I've always used the SDK. I'd recommend including your code to generate the header in your question though.

Comment: a) You should edit additional details into your question. b) You 100% have not included the code for _generating_ the header in your question. You've simply included the variable `authorizationHeader`, but we have no idea how that variable came into being. It could simply be `string authorizationHeader = "hello";`, in which case it definitely wouldn't work as an authorization header. Signatures usually involve hashing, etc. and there's none of that in your question.

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update 12/19:**

When using [Put Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-range) to upload content to azure file, you can follow the following code(I assume you have already created a file on the azure file share, and **it's content length is larger than the content being uploaded**):

```
        static void UploadText()
        {
            string Account = "xxxx";
            string Key = "xxxx";
            string FileShare = "test1";
            string FileName = "11.txt";
            string apiversion = "2019-02-02";

            //the string to be uploaded to azure file, note that the length of the uploaded string should less than the azure file length
            string upload_text = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.";
            Console.WriteLine("the string length: " + upload_text.Length);
            DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
            string StringToSign = String.Format("PUT\n"
                + "\n" // content encoding
                + "\n" // content language
                + upload_text.Length + "\n" // content length
                + "\n" // content md5
                + "\n" // content type
                + "\n" // date
                + "\n" // if modified since
                + "\n" // if match
                + "\n" // if none match
                + "\n" // if unmodified since
                + "\n"//+ "bytes=0-" + (upload_text.Length - 1) + "\n" // range
                +"x-ms-date:" + dt.ToString("R") + "\nx-ms-range:bytes=0-"+(upload_text.Length-1) + "\nx-ms-version:" + apiversion + "\nx-ms-write:update\n" // headers
                + "/{0}/{1}/{2}\ncomp:range", Account, FileShare, FileName);

            string auth = SignThis(StringToSign, Key, Account);
            string method = "PUT";
            string urlPath = string.Format("https://{0}.file.core.windows.net/{1}/{2}?comp=range", Account, FileShare,FileName);
            Uri uri = new Uri(urlPath);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = method;
            request.ContentLength = upload_text.Length;

            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-range", "bytes=0-"+(upload_text.Length-1));
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-write", "update");
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", dt.ToString("R"));
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", apiversion);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
            //request.Headers.Add("Content-Length", upload_text.Length.ToString());

            var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(upload_text);

            using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }


            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                //read the content
                Console.WriteLine("the response is:" + response.StatusCode);
            }
        }



        private static String SignThis(String StringToSign, string Key, string Account)
        {
            String signature = string.Empty;
            byte[] unicodeKey = Convert.FromBase64String(Key);
            using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(unicodeKey))
            {
                Byte[] dataToHmac = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StringToSign);
                signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
            }

            String authorizationHeader = String.Format(
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                  "{0} {1}:{2}",
                  "SharedKey",
                  Account,
                  signature);

            return authorizationHeader;
        }
```

Then in the `Main()` method, you can call `UploadText()` method, it works at my side.

---

**old:**

> guide me how to write content to a simple file on azure storage
>   without using the azure client API.

For this, you can directly use Azure File Storage SDK [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File, version 11.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File/). And we always recommend using SDK instead of using rest api, because the SDK is easy to use.

Here is an example of using this SDK.

First, create a console project of .NET framework in visual studio. Then install this nuget package [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File, version 11.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File/).

The code:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File;
using System;

namespace AzureFileTest2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string accountName = "xxx";
            string accountKey = "xxx";
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);

            CloudFileClient cloudFileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

            //make sure the file share named test1 exists.
            CloudFileShare fileShare = cloudFileClient.GetShareReference("test1");
            CloudFileDirectory fileDirectory = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
            CloudFile myfile = fileDirectory.GetFileReference("test123.txt");

            if (!myfile.Exists())
            {
                //if the file does not exists, then create the file and set the file max size to 100kb.
                myfile.Create(100 * 1024 * 1024);                
            }

            //upload text to the file
            //Besides using UploadText() method to directly upload text, you can also use UploadFromFile() / UploadFromByteArray() / UploadFromStream() methods as per your need.
            myfile.UploadText("hello, it is using azure storage SDK");

            Console.WriteLine("**completed**");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am restricted not to to use the Azure File Storage SDK, we have to make it work using rest api,

Comment: @RahilaSyed, ok, then what's the meaning of "or just guide me how to write content to a simple file on azure storage without using the azure client API." in your post? I will try to use rest api for this, and update you later.

Comment: @RahilaSyed, please see the updated section. And let me know if you still have more issues about that.