# Exchanging authorization code for refresh and access tokens OAuth2

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to exchange the authorization code I got in [this step](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#step-2:-send-a-request-to-googles-oauth-2.0-server) of the documentation for refresh and access tokens. Where I'm stuck is how to send a request for the Json that contains the access and refresh tokens as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#exchange-authorization-code).

This is my code:

```cs
string paras = string.Format("code={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&grant_type={4}&redirect_uri={3}",
    AuthCode,
    ClientID,
    ClientSecret,
    "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
    "authorization_code"
);
var req = WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token/") as HttpWebRequest;
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(paras);
req.ContentLength = data.Length;
using (Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream())
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
req.GetResponse();
```

`System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.'` is being thrown at `req.GetResponse();`.

My two theories are either I need to add a redirect uri in the developer console and use that or add a code verifier.

Comment: ContentType is usually `text/plain` for exchanging the code for token requests. Do you get any more info why it's `BadRequest`

Comment: With either content type all I get is `System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.'`.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing correct value for grant_type and redirect_uri parameters?

Comment: I'm sure about `grant_type` but not about `redirect_uri`.

Comment: `redirect_uri` is something you configure at the time of creating app in google. You need to use the same redirect_uri value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `redirect_uri` must be the same as [when the authorization code was requested](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#step-2:-send-a-request-to-googles-oauth-2.0-server).

I also missed [this step](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#step1-code-verifier). The `code_challenge` can be the same as `code_verifier` but only if `code_challenge_method` is `plain`. The documentation says that it is only "recommended" for requesting the authorization code when it is in fact required for later.

Answer (score 1):

When issuing a request to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth` to initiate the OAuth2 flow and obtain an Auth Code ([OAuth 2.0 Step 2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#step-2:-send-a-request-to-googles-oauth-2.0-server)), the `redirect_uri` parameter accepts the special `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` URI to specify manual copy/paste of the obtained response.

However, in the [OAuth 2.0 Step 5](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#exchange-authorization-code) (exchanging auth code for refresh & access token) the `redirect_uri` parameter does **not** accept the aforementioned URI, so you will have to use a valid one that has been set up in your GCP project (you can add one by going to credentials>your credential>Authorized redirect URIs).

Furthermore, in order to debug response errors returned by the API, I suggest you check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261986/how-to-get-error-information-when-httpwebrequest-getresponse-fails) that describes how to obtain and print the information that is returned along with a failed request.